# Stop migrations from a particular gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apartment-gem

I am working on a multi tenant rails app where the tenants have been created using Apartment gem. Whenever a new tenant is created, Apartment creates all the tables in the new tenant.

But, when I add a new table and run db:migrate, one of the gems, tries to recreate the tables in the tenants and it fails because the table already exists(created by Apartment). It throws PGSQL error :: table already exists.

- How do I tell that particular gem to not run its migrations as its tables have already been created by Apartment?
- Is it possible to remove/stop/halt migrations for a particular gem ?

OR,

- Is it possible to ask Apartment gem to not create the tables so that the other gem can create them?

Comment: How are you creating and migrating the Tenants?  My suspicion is however you have it setup is not updating the migration table for the tenants.

Comment: I am creating using Apartment::Tenant.create('tenant_name') . It creates all the tables for me. I don't know if its updating the migration table. I will try and figure that out.